# Stack Overflow snippet "begin snippet" purpose

Tags: bug, stack-snippets

Stack snippets have three parameters:

- begin snippet
- hide
- babel

`hide` hides the snippet so it doesn't take up too much space, `babel` probably does something complicated that I don't understand, but `begin snippet` doesn't seem to do anything.

From the name, it sounds like it should define which block of code should come first in the rendered output, but that is not the case:

```js
console.log('JavaScript');
```

```css
.CSS { }
```

```html
<div>HTML</div>
```

When I set `begin snippet: css` or `begin snippet: html` it still starts with JavaScript. Is this a bug, or does `begin snippet` do something else?

Comment: It’s `hide: true` or `hide: false` and `babel: true` or `babel: false`, not `true babel` or just `hide`. And [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) is used for transpilation.

Comment: @Xufox Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: I think `begin snippet: js` means JavaScript and JS related technologies. Maybe in the future there will be Python snippets that have `begin snippet: python` and if Python has related technologies, these will be included as blocks as well.

Comment: And it could be `begin` `snippet: js` `hide: false` `babel: true`

Comment: I had never heard the term "transpilation"!  Thanks @Xufox !

Comment: *"A **source-to-source compiler** (S2S compiler), **transcompiler** or **transpiler** is a type of compiler that takes the source code of a program written in a programming language as its input and produces the equivalent source code in the same or a different programming language. A source-to-source compiler translates between programming languages that operate at approximately the same level of abstraction, while a traditional compiler translates from a higher level programming language to a lower level programming language."* (Source: [wiki](//wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-to-source_compiler))